# Difference between execution costs on remix an Ganache?

Tags: remix, gas, gas-limit, ganache

I created a contract on remix and then deployed it. when I call any function there is an execution cost in gas.  I also deployed the same contract on Ganache for testing. I find the execution cost in remix is 525424 gas but in Ganache, i found the gas used 1214584 gas. 
**Is the execution costs in remix is accurate, Is it simulate the actual execution costs on etherum network?** 
**How can I know the execution cost in ganache?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's hard to say without the code and exact txs you used. Seeing as it is a contract deployment, a simple difference could be enabling/disabling optimization

Comment: If I want to estimate the execution cost in gas, can I depend on numbers shown in the remix?

Comment: If you are deploying the exact same bytecode you are estimating against, it is reasonably accurate. If you make changes to configurations/optimizations/set values that change the code paths taken, then you will need to estimate again against the new state

Comment: Okay. I understand remix. Do you know how I get the gas cost in Ganache?. For me, I deployed the same Bytecode. But I do not how to get the actual execution cost on Ganache?

Comment: Solc can output the gas estimates, the documentation has examples on how.

Comment: Any updates to this question?  I’m experiencing a similar issue.